# Applying rolling function return no value pandas

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation, pandas-rolling

I have a data frame temps that looks like this

[image]

And I am trying to apply a shift of 1 and then a rolling function with window 2 and finally taking the mean of the rolling data frame, see below code for reference,

```
shifted = temps.shift(1)
window = shifted.rolling(2)
means = window.mean()
```

but I am getting an error like below:

> DataError: No numeric types to aggregate

when I print the window, I get an output like below":

[image]

Can someone please tell me why I am receiving a DataError on calculating mean() of rolling output? and is the rolling function used correctly here?

Comment: can you try this line and see if you get the same error (assuming you've imported `pd` and `np`): `pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(3650)).shift(1).rolling(2).mean()`

Comment: @tdy : I ran the above line and it ran successfully, but when I put my dataframe temps in place of np.random.random(3650) it again starts giving me the same error :

DataError: No numeric types to aggregate

Is there something I need to fix with the dataframe?

Comment: try explicitly converting to `float` first. this isn't necessary on my end even if there are non-numerics in the data, but maybe it's a version issue: `temps.astype(float).shift(1).rolling(2).mean()`

Comment: @tdy - Thanks, it worked!! all it required was float conversion.. Thanks!!